# Jtable field options not display json because it contains /(slashes)

Tags: wcf, json.net, jquery-jtable

My wcf project returns the Countries List as json, in wcf project parse using Newtonsoft json. I get json in my client website built on mvc, i show the data using jtable plugin in jquery. The plugin failed to display because, the json contains /(back slashes).

Code to display jtable is

```
 Name:{
                    title: 'Country Name',
                    width: '40%',
                    options: '/Country/Index'
}
```

Country/Index result is

```
{"Result":"OK","Options":"[{\"DisplayText\":\"India\",\"Value\":1},{\"DisplayText\":\"Singapore\",\"Value\":2}]"}
```

Country/Index gets the result from wcf service. Is there any way to strip the / in json.

Edit:
My wcf code is

```
 List<JSONDisplayNameValue> lstLanguages = new List<JSONDisplayNameValue>();
//Get data from db. 
//JSONDisplayNameValue has two variables DisplayName, Value
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstLanguages);
        return  json;
```

Country/Index mvc code is

```
public JsonResult Index()
    {
        string Countries_list = processsvc.GetAllCountries();
        return Json(new { Result = "OK", Options = Countries_list },  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Be precise: there are no slashes in your result, only backslashes. You may add your backoffice `Index` code to see why you got them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting backslashes because you are double-serializing your data.

- In your WCF code, you call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` to serialize your list of countries/languages to JSON before returning it.
- In your MVC controller, you call your WCF service to get the list, which is already in JSON format.  But then you add that JSON to another object and call `Json()` which causes the list to be serialized a second time.  That is where the backslashes get added.

To fix this, you either need to

- Deserialize the list you get back from your WCF service before adding it to the MVC result.

  -- OR --
- Make a way to retrieve your list of countries/languages without serializing it to JSON.  Then add the unserialized list to your MVC result and serialize it as normal.